# google charts character accents in title in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, charts, google-visualization

I uses Laravel to display Google charts, but unfortunately the titles with accented characters is not correctly displayed

```
     @foreach($barcs as $barc)
      [ '{{$barc->titre}}',  {{$barc->nbr}}],
     @endforeach
```

Comment: check the spellings, check if there is any data in database, check wheather the first data is the title like `['title-description', 'number-description']`

Comment: Does the accented character display properly when not in a Google chart?

Answer (score 0):

All display text passed to the Chart API must be UTF-8 encoded and then URL-encoded. Try outputting your titles like this:

```
@foreach($barcs as $barc)
    [ '{{htmlentities($barc->titre, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8")}}',  {{$barc->nbr}}],
@endforeach
```

This will convert the accented characters to something that Google Charts can handle.

`somèthing with añ accent` gets sent to Google as `som&egrave;thing with a&ntilde; accent`

If that doesn't work, could you let us know what the accented characters that you are not being correctly displayed are?

Comment: Sorry does not work, in below the accented characters

Office d&#039;Etude D&#039;Arbit

this is The correct sentence : Office d'Etude D'Arbit

Comment: Are you getting JavaScript errors when your charts code runs? Perhaps you need to use double quotes surrounding your `{{$barc->titre}}`, or escape the accents with a `\\` before them.

Comment: There is no error in Javascript the charts is displayed very well except the title! I changed the double quotation, but always the same error in the title!